# How to read star (*) as system command

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
> >>> import os
> >>> os.chdir('/u01/APPLTOP/instance/domains/*.oracleoutsourcing.com/ICDomain/servers/IncentiveCompensationServer_1/logs')
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/u01/APPLTOP/instance/domains/*.oracleoutsourcing.com/ICDomain/servers/IncentiveCompensationServer_1/logs'
> >>>
```

Can you please let me know how can I read asterisk (*) as Linux system command in python.

Comment: what do you mean by system command? You mean glob? Then how come it switched to more no of directories at a time.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? You want to use a wildcard? To change directory? Why? What if there are multiple matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simulate [shell path expansion](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Path_name_expansion) of '*' (as well as other glob special characters), you can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
glob_pattern = '/u01/APPLTOP/instance/domains/*.oracleoutsourcing.com/ICDomain/servers/IncentiveCompensationServer_1/logs'
dir_paths = glob.glob(glob_pattern)
```

Now, assuming the above results with a single match (otherwise, it makes no sense "chdir"ing ot it), you can do:

```
dir_path, = dir_paths
os.chdir(dir_path)
```

The assingment above fails if you get no matches, or multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not a "command", let alone a "Linux system command". Rather the shell (basically a tool for starting other programs) will take your commandline, replace variables like `$FOO` and wildcards like `*` according to its rules, then build a vector of arguments which are then passed to the invoked program.

Now, as already mentioned in the comments, the asterisk replacement is called globbing. Using that as a term in a websearch, you should easily find suitable code online. If you have problems implementing one of the methods you find there, don't hesitate asking here.